# Filtering QTreeView with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have a tree like this:

header 1  header2  header3

node1

--node2

----node3  value1  value2

----node4  value3  value4

Etc...

I need to filter model for different values in the same row.
That is, if value1  is the same (equal) with value2, then skip this line, if not - display.

There is some sample code:

```
class FindFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    if (self.filterAcceptsRowItself(source_row, source_parent)):
        return True

    if (self.hasAcceptedChildren(source_row, source_parent)):
        return True

    return False

def filterAcceptsRowItself(self, source_row, source_parent):
    return super(FindFilterProxyModel, self).\
    filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)

def hasAcceptedChildren(self, source_row, source_parent):
    model = self.sourceModel()
    sourceIndex = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
    if not (sourceIndex.isValid()):
        return False

    childCount = model.rowCount(sourceIndex)
    if (childCount == 0):
        return False

    for i in range (childCount): 
        if (self.filterAcceptsRowItself(i, sourceIndex)):
            return True
        # recursive call -> NOTICE that this is depth-first searching,
        # you're probably better off with breadth first search...
        if (self.hasAcceptedChildren(i, sourceIndex)):
            return True

    return False
```

It recursively compares the values in the first column (use this for the search).
And I want to compare that to all columns except the first one.

Comment: You've said what you want to do and provided some code. But what is your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: Note  that this approach with filtering parents by their children's properties is fragile as soon as the children are modified; from what I remember, filterAcceptsRow won't be called for the parent again when the child changes, so its filter state won't be updated.

Comment: @three_pineapples "I need to filter model for different values in the same row. That is, if value1 is the same (equal) with value2, then skip this line, if not - display."

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thank you! I know that and I have 'refresh button' for this case.

Comment: @Max_Tar Quoting part of the question at me is not going to help me understand. I did already read the whole of your question. I still don't understand what you are looking for in answer. I know what you need, but **what is your question?. You don't appear to have actually asked a question in your post.** What part of implementing a solution using `QSortFilterProxyModel` are you having trouble with?

Comment: @three_pineapples, man, i can't understand how i will compare different values in one row, but different columns.

Comment: @three_pineapples, i have a 3 columns. I need to reimplement QSortFilterProxyModel so, that only nodes with different values will diplay.
So, i need an idea, how i can compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help somebody. This code compares values in two columns.

```
class DiffFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    # Check if the model is valid
    model = self.sourceModel()
    if model is None:
        return False

    # get index for first column of the row
    src_index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)

    # recursively compare the values in tree
    for i in range (model.rowCount(src_index)):
        child_index = src_index.child(i, 0)
        c1 = child_index.sibling(child_index.row(), 1).data()
        c2 = child_index.sibling(child_index.row(), 2).data()

        if (c1 != c2 or self.filterAcceptsRow(i, src_index)):
            return super(DiffFilterProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)                                                   

    c1 = src_index.sibling(src_index.row(), 1).data()
    c2 = src_index.sibling(src_index.row(), 2).data()

    return c1 != c2 and super(DiffFilterProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)
```

Thanks to grondek for his help.